# an issue with the execution time of a VQC classifier on an IBM quantum machine

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qiskit-runtime, variational-quantum-algorithms

I tried to use the available open-source IBM quantum machines. I’m trying to do a classification using the VQC classifier to classify data, but I encountered a problem. The VQC keeps fitting on the training data and each time a new job is created. I don’t know how to fix this issue so I can know the accuracy of the training. The execution never ends within a certain amount of time and on the platform, each time a new job is created. I tried taking only a small portion of the dataset, but it didn’t work. I even tried to minimize the number of shots used.

Does anyone know what could cause such issue?